# Windows FINDSTR Ubuntu equivalent to search .csv

Tags: command-line, csv

I have a folder (Transactions) with hundreds of .csv files. I want to search through all csv files for a particular string and get the output of each line that contains that string. Preferably output to a txt file.
For example, let's say I want to find any record that contains the name John Doe. In windows I would use the following:

```
FINDSTR /n /i "John.Doe" *.csv >> johndoe.txt
```

- `/n` to give me the line number
- `/i` to ignore case
- `"."` to separate words
- `*.csv` to search all files that end with .csv, and
- `>>` to output to a new file which contains all data that includes the string (into the same folder).

I'm looking for a similar command to use in Ubuntu Terminal that will search through all .csv files and output any hits to a txt file. I've looked into grep and awk but don't know how to use them.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can use sed, grep, awk, perl and likely other tools as well. Give a more specific example of your input file and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

> I've looked into grep and awk but don't know how to use them.

The grep documentation has [plenty of examples.](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Usage) The first one in the *Usage* section demonstrates case-insensitive searching:

> Here is an example command that invokes GNU `grep`:
>
> ```
>  grep -i 'hello.*world' menu.h main.c
> ```
>
> ... The `-i` option causes `grep` to ignore case, causing it to match
>   the line ‘`Hello, world!`’, which it would not otherwise match.

And if I search for `line number` in the aforementioned page:

```
-n
--line-number
Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file. (-n is specified by POSIX.)
```

`>> foo` and `*.csv` are handled by the shell (probably how you'd expect). So:

```
grep -in "John.Doe" *.csv >> johndoe.txt
```

Options like `/i`, `/n`, etc. usually begin with hyphens in the Unix world.

Answer (score 0):

The free application 'CsvFileSearch' will do exactly what you want.

http://webmayo.com/csvfilesearch